# Run script to fetch SVN latest revision number does not work with XCode 5.0

Tags: objective-c, xcode, svn

We were using the below run script to capture the checkin revision number at build time and this works fine until we migrated to XCode 5.0. With XCode 5 (which uses SVN 1.7) this does not seems to work. Anyone faced the similar issue? Is there any fix for this without upgrading SVN version to 1.7?

```
REV=`svnversion -nc | /usr/bin/sed -e 's/^[^:]*://;s/[A-Za-z]//'`
echo "Setting CFBundleShortVersionString to "$REV
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleShortVersionString $REV" "${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${INFOPLIST_PATH}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't tell exactly what does not work. Have you looked in the build log?

But what I assume, is that your svnversion command returns an error like the following:
"svn: E200030: sqlite: callback requested query abort"

This is discussed in a lot of fora.

What worked for me was an 'svn upgrade', and then an 'svn cleanup'.

source: https://trac.macports.org/ticket/33751